# Save selected data of a variable to use in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a list of items that are filled dynamically:

```
     function ViewData(data) {
        var SI = (typeof data) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
        $('#ListContainer').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < SI.length; i++) {
            var text = '<a href="Page.htm" rel="external" onclick= "SaveData();"
                         class="lesson" LessonID="' + SI[i].lessonID 
                         '"><span class="lesson_subject">' + SI[i].sbj_Name + 
                         '</span></b></a>
            $('#ListContainer').append(text).trigger("create");
        }
    }
```

When one item of them is clicked, the page should navigate to another page carrying the data of this link.

I made this function to save the values of found in the link:

```
function SaveData() {
        localStorage["LessonID"] = $('#ListContainer').find('.lesson').attr('LessonID'); 
        localStorage["SubjectName"] = $('#ListContainer').find('.lesson_subject').text();
        }
```

but it saves "All of the data". I want to save the data of the selected item only. 
Do you have any ideas ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It saves all of the data because your `find('.lesson')` will find every link inside `#ListContainer`. I would suggest removing your inline event handlers and taking advantage of event delegation with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("#ListContainer").on("click", ".lesson", function() {
    localStorage["LessonID"] = $(this).data("lessonid");
    localStorage["SubjectName"] = $(this).data("subject");
});
```

Notice that I've used the `data` method instead of `attr`. That will require another change to your markup:

```
<a href="Page.htm" rel="external" class="lesson" data-lessonid="someID" data-subject="someSubject">
```

This uses HTML5 `data-*` attributes, which are the recommended approach when it comes to storing arbitrary data on an element.

---

Why use event delegation? It is more efficient, as it results in less event handlers bound to elements. Instead of one on every `a.lesson` element, there is just one on the `#ListContainer` element.

Because most DOM events bubble up the tree, a click on a descendant of `#ListContainer` will bubble up through the DOM tree, eventually reaching `#ListContainer`. The jQuery `on` method will pick up the event at this element, and check to see if it originated at an element matching `.lesson`. If so, it will execute the event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
onclick= "SaveData();"
```

to

```
onclick= "SaveData(this);"
```

Then change the `saveData` function to

```
function SaveData(elem) {
        localStorage["LessonID"] = $(elem).attr('LessonID'); 
        localStorage["SubjectName"] = $(elem).find('.lesson_subject').text();
        }
```

Or even better, you can use `$.on` like @James Allardice showed in his answer.

Comment: Was just about to type the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing old world JavaScript and jQuery.

Use `$("<a ...")` to create your element, append it and then attach a .click handler which can use `$(this)` when it is fired. Use .data to add data to the elements when you add them which the .click handler can utilise.